# Type of community to expect

Tags: discussion, support, new-users

I was actually extremely excited about the emacs community but that was short lived when I asked my first question which showed what I have done so it was not just a problem statement begging for help. My question: is this going to be a community where snide, incorrect comments are acceptable and even approved since it is being upvoted? I say this in reference to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10229/emacs-setup-not-working-on-a-different-computer#comment15474_10229). The user is telling me I am making something up when I am fully capable of reading the output produced in the command line. Great introduction to the community. Is this to be norm? If so, this not an inviting community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, welcome to the community, I'm sorry you had a bad first impression.

I just had a look at the question, and I'll try to clarify. Those comments are not being unpolite, they're just confused because they didn't understand what you meant with that sentence. I understand what you tried to say, so I'll go there and clarify now.

In the mean time, take a breath. Try to see those comments as light-hearted, for they certainly weren't offensive. They were just trying to understand what you meant with that sentence because it means nothing in Emacs terms.
Miscommunication is the most common issue of the internet, so I'm sure we don't need to blame that on this community or any of the participants.